# Excel sum value if month equals value

Tags: excel

The function needs to iterate through the cells and if the value is the right month (8, 9, etc.), then it needs to add the value of another cell. All of my dates are within B3:B300, and all of my totals arew within K3:K300.

For example:

```
A1      A2       A3
8/8/14  8/10/14  9/10/14

B1      B2       B3
20      40       30
```

If I was looking for the sum for August, in this example it would be 60.

This is the formula I attempted, but didnt get the desired results:

```
=SUM(IF(--(MONTH('Transaction Financials'!B3:B300))=8,--('Transaction Financials'!K3:K300),0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2:A4) = 8), B2:B4)
```