# EXcel, sum the quantity of distinct products where month is January

Tags: excel, sum, distinct, product

I have a table in Excel:

```
Date               Product           Quantity

1/4/2016             A               3

1/4/2016             B               2

1/8/2016             A               7

2/3/2016             B               5

2/5/2016             B               1

2/8/2016             A               4
```

I need to count how many A products was sold in January (no matter the day, just month), f.e:

```
A in January was sold 10,
B in January was sold 2,
A in February was sold 4
B in Feruary was sold 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SUMPRODUCT`, for example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A1:A2)=1) * (B1:B2="A") * C1:C2)
```

In the above I'm assuming date to be in column A, product to be in column B and the range you want to sum in C. Also as it's just an example I'm just summing the first two rows

I referenced SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827223/excel-sum-value-if-month-equals-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SUMIFS:-

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"A",A:A,">="&DATEVALUE("1/1/2016"),A:A,"<"&DATEVALUE("1/2/2016"))
```

or

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"A",A:A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2016,2,1))
```

where my dates are in DD/MM/YYYY format.

But if you want to repeat it for many combinations of date and product, you might be better off putting the month into a separate column and using a Pivot table.